# Modx Revo API как разобрать массив получаемых пользователей?

Tags: php, modx

Так я определяю нужную группу пользователей (их всего 4)

```
$group = $modx->getObject('modUserGroup', array ('id' => '2'));
$users = $group->getMany('UserGroupMembers');
```

Теперь в массиве `$users` у нас находятся пользователи из нужной нам группы. Сделал проверку `count($users)` показало **4** - 4 пользователя в этой группе. Правильно.

Теперь пытаюсь разобрать массив по пользователям.

```
foreach ($users as $user){

// получаем имя и id пользователя
$name = $user->get('username'); //name
$uid = $user->get('id'); //id

// связь с профилем пользователя
$profile = $user->getOne('Profile');
$isUserBlocked = $profile->get('blocked'); // заблокирован ли юзер
$extendedFields = $profile->get('extended'); // доп поля
$age = $extendedFields['age']; // возраст получили из доп полей
$unitsAge = $modx->runSnippet("units", array('input' => $age, 'options' => 'год|года|лет')); //компонент units
// выводим данные
if(!preg_match("/(.*?)admin(.*)/iu", $name)){ //не выводим админа
if($isUserBlocked != '1'){ // не выводим заблокированых юзеров
echo '
<div class="usersforu boxs">
<div class="ufuName">'.$name.'</div>
<div class="ufuAge">Возраст: '.$age.' '.$unitsAge.'</div>

...

</div>
';
}
}



//end for each
}
```

Проблема в том, что не выводится ничего из цикла, ошибок нет. Может как-то по-другому нужно разбирать массив?

Comment: `var_dump($users)` и смотрите что там в переменной

Comment: получаю это, как с этим работать? **array(4) { [180]=> object(modUserGroupMember_mysql)#50 (25) { ["xpdo"]=> object(modX)#1 (73) { ["context"]=> object(modContext_mysql)#6 (33) { ["config"]=> array(0) { } ["aliasMap"]=> &array(14) { ["index"]=> int(1) ["unavailable"]=> int(4) ["sign-in"]=> int(5) ["sign-up"]=> int(6) [404]=> int(8) ["exit"]=> int(9) ["robots.txt"]=> int(2) ["sitemap.xml"]=> int(3) ["user/"]=> int(12) ["user/profile"]=> int(7) ["user/edit"]=> int(10) ["user/edit-photos"]=> int(15) ["user/pass"]=> int(11) ["user/searching"]=> int(13) } ["resourceMap"]=> &array(2) { [0**

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте метод $user->toArray(), который должен возвращает все поля объекта в виде массива. значение объекта обычно получается как $user->get("имя поля в БД, с которым связано свойство") А вообще почитайте про XPDO (https://docs.modx.pro/sistema/xpdo/klass-xpdo).